# matlab has encountered an internal problem needs to close

Tags: matlab

when click matlab Registration(use the NFRI function)，occur matlab has encountered an internal problem needs to close.
[click matlab Registration(use the NFRI function)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrhob.jpg)

this is the error detail.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Sun Mar 31 11:08:39 2024
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Default Encoding   : GBK
  MATLAB Architecture: win64
  MATLAB Root        : E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013
  MATLAB Version     : 8.2.0.701 (R2013b)
  Operating System   : Microsoft Windows 8
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 175 Model 80 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : Version 6.2 (Build 9200)

Fault Count: 2


Abnormal termination:
Illegal instruction

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000096366000  RBX = 0000000096367000
  RCX = 00000000043ef6b0  RDX = 0000000096797800
  RSP = 00000000043ef4c0  RBP = 00000000043eff80
  RSI = 00000000043eff88  RDI = 00000000043eff80
 
   R8 = 0000000000000080   R9 = 0000000096367000
  R10 = 0000000000000780  R11 = 0000000000000280
  R12 = 0000000000000004  R13 = 0000000000000048
  R14 = 0000000000000004  R15 = 0000000000000004
 
  RIP = 00000001317805b2  EFL = 00010212
 
   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00000001317805b2 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\mkl.dll+24642994 xerbla+22640098
[  1] 0x0000000130dbd484 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\mkl.dll+14406788 xerbla+12403892
[  2] 0x0000000130db2db8 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\mkl.dll+14364088 xerbla+12361192
[  3] 0x00000001300d10e5 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\mkl.dll+00856293 mkl_cbwr_set+00472453
[  4] 0x0000000130019d5a E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\mkl.dll+00105818 dgemm+00000362
[  5] 0x000000005d0eac3b E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+00437307 UMFPACK_ComplexLUFactor::extractFactors+00103211
[  6] 0x000000005d0eb21d E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+00438813 mfMatrixMult+00000125
[  7] 0x000000005d0ecec3 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+00446147 mfMatrixMult+00007459
[  8] 0x000000005d0ecfd6 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+00446422 mfMatrixMult+00007734
[  9] 0x000000005d0ed1e3 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+00446947 mfMatrixMult+00008259
[ 10] 0x000000018000d7ff E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00055295 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00001167
[ 11] 0x000000018000ddb7 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00056759 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000487
[ 12] 0x0000000011c268a7 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00420007 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00242727
[ 13] 0x0000000011c29b38 E:\Matlab2013b\Mingchuan Matlab2013B\matlab2013\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00432952 inFunctionHandleInterface::DestroyWorkspace+00255672
```

1、uninstall and reinstall,but also occur

expect result：
can run success

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should report that to the MathWorks, we can’t fix bugs in MATLAB. But since you’re using an 11-year old version of MATLAB, they’re not likely to help you other than tell you to upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: Bit in terms of a Stack Overflow question, what are you asking? Please be explicit about your question!